# Can I overwrite select options in jQueryUI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qrg9A/100/)

I have an autocomplete code in my main js file. Here's an example:

```
var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp"
    ];
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      return false; 
    }
});
```

And I have a separate js file that will only be served up on a specific page. In that file, I want to overwrite the `select` option in the `$("#tags")` instance, here's an example in that seperate js file:

```
$.widget( "ui.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
   select: function (event, ui) {
     $(this).val(ui.item.label);  // to automatically populate the input box with the selected option  
  }
});
```

Is it possible to overwrite the select option like that in jQuery?

Comment: Just to make sure, you don't just want to change the `select` function in the `$("#tags")` _instance_, right? You want to change `select` in all instances of the autocomplete widget?

Comment: @slicedtoad, I want to change the instance of $('#tags') only. Can I do that using something like extend function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `option` method. All jQuery widgets have an [option method](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-option) that allows you to change options. And all jQuery widget methods are called like `$().widgetname("method",arg1,arg2,...)`

http://jsfiddle.net/b9awbcuf/

```
$("#tags").autocomplete("option", "select", function (event, ui) {
    alert('changed');
    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
});
```

This is a *very* useful read: http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/how-jquery-ui-works/